# Rails/Ruby - Prepopulate form with data passed from another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get values to prepopulate a new `device` form when navigating to it from `rfid` partial of `view/cabinet/show` page?  `device` has_one `rfid`.

The link from cabinet/show:

```
<%= link_to "Create New Device (non-functional)", new_device_path({:id => @rfid.id, cabinet_id: @cabinet.id}), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

The `devices_controller`, I want to have the create method work when either 0 or 2 params are passed:

```
def create(options)

if options[:cabinet_id] and options[:id]
  @rfid = Rfid.find(params[:id])
  @device = Device.new(params[:device])
  @device.rfid = @rfid
  @device.cabinet_id = :cabinet_id

else
  @device = Device.new(params[:device])
  @cabinet = Cabinet.find(params[:device][:cabinet_id])
  @device.row_id = @cabinet.row_id
end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @device.save and @cabinet.refresh_capacity_used and @cabinet.refresh_consumption
      format.html { redirect_to @device, notice: 'Device was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @device, status: :created, location: @device }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @device.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

end

The cabinet_id and rfid portion of new `device/_form`:

```
<tr>
        <th>Cabinet</th>
        <td><%= f.select :cabinet_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Cabinet.order(:name).all, "id", "name", @device.cabinet_id) %></td>
</tr>


<tr>
        <th>RFID</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :rfid, :value => params[:rfid]%></td> 
</tr>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you only trying to get the RFID field to prepopulate?

Comment: No, just taking it one step at a time. Hopefully if I figure out rfid, I'll get cabinet on my own.

Comment: I've answered with code that should pre-populate both fields. Can you tell me if it works?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have:

```
<%= link_to "Create New Device (non-functional)", new_device_path({:id => @rfid.id, :cabinet_id => @cabinet.id}), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

you can get prepopulate the `rfid` and `cabinet_id` fields using:

```
<%= f.select :cabinet_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Cabinet.order(:name).all, "id", "name", params[:cabinet_id]) %>

<%= f.text_field :rfid, :value => params[:id] %>
```

Note that your params key must match the value passed into the hash in your `link_to` tag.

Comment: Awesome!  I had to fiddle a bit but you definitely got me on the right path.

Comment: Except that `_form.rb` is also used by the `edit` action, and now editing those values is broken.

Comment: @aidan, you've gotta be kidding; if your `_form.rb` values are being affected, you have them incorrectly mapped. Also, providing some context around the problem you're experiencing would be helpful, particularly in following up to an answer that is three years old. What version Rails are you even using? The version has been bumped several times since this question was answered.

Comment: @zeantsoi I'm assuming you're suggesting he replaces `<%= f.text_field :rfid %>` with `<%= f.text_field :rfid, :value => params[:id] %>`  in `_form.html.erb`? If he does that, then yes, the value will default to `params[:id]`. But if `_form.html.erb` is being included by `edit.html.erb` because the user is trying to edit an existing `@device`, then the `rfid` value of that `@device` will be clobbered.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't had more interest.
In order to prevent the clobbering, I used: `<%= f.label :datetimeRecordedAt %><br> <% if @artefact.ingestedFileTimezone %> <%= f.text_field :datetimeRecordedAt %><% else %><%= f.text_field :datetimeRecordedAt, :value => Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") %><% end %>`

Comment: I finally found a way to prevent this: change `<%= f.select :cabinet_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Cabinet.order(:name).all, "id", "name", params[:cabinet_id]) %>` to `<%= f.select :cabinet_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Cabinet.order(:name).all, "id", "name", params[:cabinet_id] || @device.cabinet_id) %>`. This way, if `params[:cabinet_id]` is empty, then `@device.cabinet_id` (the existing value) will be used instead.

Answer (score 6):

@zeantsoi's answer as posted mostly works, but it breaks the editing functionality. As a fix, I propose the following minor modification:

```
<%= f.select :cabinet_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Cabinet.order(:name).all, "id", "name", params[:cabinet_id] || @device.cabinet_id) %>

<%= f.text_field :rfid, :value => params[:rfid] || @device.rfid %>
```

This way, if `params[:cabinet_id]` is absent, `@device.cabinet_id` (the existing value) will persist.